# SAPUI5- Data binding not working

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to bind data from controller to view but for some reason I am unable to display data in the view.
I am setting the model using the following code:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(oObject);
this.getView().setModel(oModel);
console.log("DATA:-->"+ JSON.stringify(this.getView().getModel().getData()));
```

The console statement prints the data properly but in the view the data is not appearing. Am I missing something. I am unable to find the problem.

My View:

```html
.....
<form:SimpleForm
    id="iform"
    minWidth="1024"
    maxContainerCols="2" >
    <Label text="Name"/>
    <Text text="{NAME}"/>
    <Label text="Age"/>
    <Text text="{AGE}"/>
</form:SimpleForm>
.....
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your JSON look like?

Comment: It looks like this : [{"NAME":"Ajay","AGE":"35"}]

Comment: You are using an array of objects, so you should bind it accordingly : `<Text text="{/0/NAME}" />` etc

Comment: @Qualiture.. I didnot know that. Thanks! Working great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding path should be `{/0/Name}` and `{/0/AGE}`

```html
<form:SimpleForm
    id="iform"
    minWidth="1024"
    maxContainerCols="2" >
    <Label text="Name"/>
    <Text text="{/0/NAME}"/>
    <Label text="Age"/>
    <Text text="{/0/AGE}"/>
</form:SimpleForm>
```